# Application of the area formula (GMT) to derive inequality for general surface area

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, proof-explanation, geometric-measure-theory

This question is related to [Proof by induction of n-dimensional isoperimetric inequality, missing step.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976115/proof-by-induction-of-n-dimensional-isoperimetric-inequality-missing-step) Discussing the same inequality but with a different approach. Gary Lawlor shows in his 2010 print [An elementary isoperimetric proof in $n$-space](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228840441_An_elementary_isoperimetric_proof_in_n-space) a proof by induction of

> **Theorem 2.1.** Round circles, spheres and hyperspheres are the most efficient volume in all dimensions;  for any surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ enclosing volume $V$, the surface area $S$ satisfies $$ S \geq \frac{nV}{r},$$ 
>   where $r$ is the radius of the round sphere enclosing the same volume $V$.

---

Below is a verbatim copy of the author's proof up until the point where I cannot follow anymore.

**Proof:** Let $T$ be the surface of some solid $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. [...] We will use terminology familiar to $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely "volume" for $n$-volume,  "area" for ($n-1)$-volume, and "perimeter" or "length" for $(n-2)$-volume. [...] Define $r$ so that the volume $V$ of $B$ matches that of a round $n$-ball of radius $r$. [...] For each $t$ let $A(t)$ be the area of the planar slice $B \cap \{x_n =t\}$. Let $P(t)$ be its perimeter, the length of $T \cap \{x_n = t\}.$ Let $t_1$ and $t_2$ be the lowest and highest values of $x_n$ on $T$, and let $S$ be the surface area of $T$.

Under the above setup the author mentions the **basic inequality for surface area**: \begin{align} S \geq \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{P(t)^2 + A'(t)^2 }dx_n. \tag{*} \end{align}

---

**My question:** How does one prove (*)? If possible, I'd like to see an approach via geometric measure theory, in particular with the help of the coarea or area formula. Although I haven't been exposed to this theory myself I find it the easiest to self-study.

---

**My approach**: For the sake of completeness I give my own attempt to establish (*). Using:

> **Theorem** ([Volume of Submanifolds](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Area_formula#The_volume_of_submanifolds)) Let $n \leq m$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a Lipschitz injective map, $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ Lebesgue measurable (of finite measure),  then $$ \mathcal{H}^n(f(A))= \int_A Jf(y)dy. $$

with $n=1, m=2$ and $A= [t_1,t_2] \subset \mathbb{R}$. We define $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^2$ as \begin{align*}
f(t):= \begin{pmatrix}
 \int_{t_1}^t P(s) ds \\ A(t)
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Then $f$ can be seen to be Lipschitz injective (using that the solid is bounded, sufficiently smooth boundary) and $Jf(t)= \sqrt{ P(t)^2 + A'(t)^2}$, in particular we have recreated the RHS of (*). However, the identity $$ \mathcal{H}^1(f([t_1,t_2]))= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{P(t)^2 + A'(t)^2}dt $$ 
doesn't seem to be very helpful, since $\mathcal{H}^1$ is just the "length" of the curve $f([t_1,t_2])$.